# Knex.js postgresql database connection

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, express, knex.js

I'm having a bit of an issue & this is most likely a user error. I just trying to connect my `Node/Express` application to a database using `Knex.js`. I'm using [Postgres App](https://postgresapp.com/).

`migrations/20180618143210_item.js`

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    knex.schema.createTable('items', (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name');
    })
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
    knex.schema.dropTable('items')
};
```

`knexfile.js`

```
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      host : 'localhost',
      database: 'my_db',
      user: 'User',
      password: ''
    },
    migrations: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/migrations'
    },
    seeds: {
      directory: __dirname + '/db/seeds/development'
    }
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user:     'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }

};
```

When I run `knex migrate:latest` it creates the database and I can see the following `\dt` database tables when connected to `my_db` database:

```
                  List of relations
 Schema |         Name         | Type  |    Owner
--------+----------------------+-------+-------------
 public | knex_migrations      | table | User
 public | knex_migrations_lock | table | User
```

When I `select * from knex_migrations;` I'm returned:

```
 id |          name          | batch |       migration_time
----+------------------------+-------+----------------------------
  2 | 20180618143210_item.js |     1 | 2018-06-18 14:40:08.994-06
```

However, if I try to run something like `select * from items` I'm getting a `ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist` error. Am I missing something here? The same error is occuring when I try to seed the data `knex seed:run`

`items.js`

```
exports.seed = function(knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('items').del()
    .then(function () {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('items').insert([
        {id: 1, name: 'rowValue1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'rowValue2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'rowValue3'}
      ]);
    });
};
```

Error: `error: relation "items" does not exist`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why this was occurring. I wasn't returning anything out of the knex `up` & `down` functions. So instead of:

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    knex.schema.createTable('items', (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name');
    })
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
    knex.schema.dropTable('items')
};
```

I needed:

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    **return** knex.schema.createTable('items', (table) => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name');
    })
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
    **return** knex.schema.dropTable('items')
};
```

Comment: declaring up and down functions as async might be a good idea to always implicitly return promise from them